# electrical shortage?

Tags: electrical

2012 Hyundai elantra touring: Car never had problem starting. Yesterday came out to car and cd that was in player was ejected. Tried to start car - nothing. Not knowing any better, thought I needed a boost. We hooked up charger and immediately battery showed  90% charge. Took charger off, car started right away. One headlight was out, but when I started to drive away, one of the two bulbs in headlight came on. Could this be a bad ground for headlights? I should add that up to this time, check engine light was on for months (known problem - air in gas line); once the above occurred, the check engine light out, abs light on.  When I shut car off and restarted, abs light out.

Comment: Most likely a bad battery or connections at the battery need removed and cleaned.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the car in question?

Comment: If it is an incandescent head light : it may have a broken filament. The broken filament end swings around and may contact the other end and weld to it keeping the light on temporarily.

Comment: Hi Glenda - if you register, then you can easily edit your own posts without review, gain reputation, and a whole host of other privileges.